# Multiple ordinates with log y and linear scale at the same graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is possible to make graph, with one linear ordinate on the left and different on the right but logarithmical?

In MWE below, there is my attempt, which is not working. I am getting these errors:

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfplots\pgfplots.sty:227: Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfplots\pgfplots.sty:233:
>   Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, nested axis environments are not
>   supported. Please move the inner axis environment below \end{axis} and
>   use alignment options (for example named nodes, see manual) to place
>   it at the desired position.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfplots\pgfplots.sty:233:
>   TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. []]**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
      axis y line*=left,  
      y axis style=blue!75!black,  
      xlabel=vykon (dBm),
      ylabel={\textsl{BER} [--]}
    ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
      coordinates{
    (-7.740,6.20E-10)
    (-8.860,6.38E-10)
    (-9,.50,7.51E-10)
    (-10.87,1.05E-08)
    (-11.92,1.02E-08)
    (-12.97,1.63E-10)
    (-14.06,2.39E-10)
    (-15.15,3.02E-10)
    (-16.20,5.89E-10)
    (-17.33,1.19E-08)
    (-18.50,1.08E-07)
    (-19.74,7.93E-07)
    (-21.10,6.64E-06)
    (-22.55,5.78E-05)
    (-24.17,3.56E-04) 
    };
    \end{semilogyaxis}

    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=right,
      axis x line=none,
      ylabel={\textsl{BER} [--]},
      y axis style=red!75!black
    ]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
      coordinates{
        (0,0)
        (0.0148,48) 
        (0.0295,66)
        (0.0441,66)
        (0.059,45.0) 
    };
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `\begin{tikzpicture}`, have written `y axis style` instead of `y axis line style`, and have a typo on the third coordinate of the first plot: `9,.50` should be `9.50`.

[image: plotyy]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        axis y line*=left,  
        y axis line style=blue!75!black,  
        xlabel=vykon (dBm),
        ylabel={\textsl{BER} [--]}
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=x,blue] 
        coordinates{
            (-7.740,6.20E-10)
            (-8.860,6.38E-10)
            (-9.50,7.51E-10)
            (-10.87,1.05E-08)
            (-11.92,1.02E-08)
            (-12.97,1.63E-10)
            (-14.06,2.39E-10)
            (-15.15,3.02E-10)
            (-16.20,5.89E-10)
            (-17.33,1.19E-08)
            (-18.50,1.08E-07)
            (-19.74,7.93E-07)
            (-21.10,6.64E-06)
            (-22.55,5.78E-05)
            (-24.17,3.56E-04) 
        };
    \end{semilogyaxis}  

    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        ylabel={\textsl{BER} [--]},
        y axis line style=red!75!black
        ]
        \addplot[smooth,mark=*,red] 
        coordinates{
            (0,0)
            (0.0148,48) 
            (0.0295,66)
            (0.0441,66)
            (0.059,45.0) 
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```